# Verification of an Inequality

Tags: inequality

Reading the paper: "A Continuous Feedback Approach to Global Strong Stabilization of Nonlinear Systems", I came up to the following inequality:

If $ p\geq 1 $ is an odd integer, then
$$ |x-y|^p \leq 2^{p-1}|x^p - y^p| $$

Because in my research problem I deal with exponents smaller than one, after multiple tries, I created the following inequality:

If $ n \leq 1 $ and specifically $ n = \frac{1}{k} $ where $ k $ is an odd integer, then
$$ |a-b|^n \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}} |a^n - b^n|  $$

Although I have tried multiple examples that verify it, I find a hard time proving it (and I'm not sure at all that it holds!).

Does anyone have any idea if such an inequality (or a similar one) actually holds or how I could work in order to validate it or not?

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: Welcome yo Maths SX! Which inequality? The inequality with $p\ge 1$ an odd integer?

Answer (score 1):

*First inequality*:

First observe that if $x > y$ then also $x^p > y^p$ for odd p.

Consider the case where $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.
One can assume w.l.o.g. $0 < t = y/x < 1$ and one needs to prove

$(1-t)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(1 - t^p)$ or $f(t,p) = (\frac{1-t}{2})^p + \frac{t^p}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Now this is done easily since $f(0,p) = (\frac{1}{2})^p$ and $f(1,p) = \frac{1}{2}$, and the rest follows from convexity of $f(t,p)$ for all $p$.

Consider the other case where $x$ and $y$ have different sign.
One can assume w.l.o.g. $0 < t = |y/x| < 1$ and one needs to prove

$(1+t)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(1 + t^p)$ or $f(t,p) = (\frac{1+t}{2})^p - \frac{t^p}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Now this is done easily since $f(0,p) = (\frac{1}{2})^p$ and $f(1,p) = \frac{1}{2}$, and the rest follows again from curve discussion of $f(t,p)$ for all $p$.

*Second inequality*:

This one doesn't hold.  Here is a counterexample for $n = 1/3$: Your claim is:

$
|1 -0.9|^{1/3} \leq 2^{3} |1 - 0.9^{1/3}|
$

however the LHS $\simeq 0.464159$ and the RHS $\simeq 0.276085 $  which gives a contradiction.